# laravel event listener not working in server

Tags: laravel, events, listener

I've a event listener in my project . it is working fine in my local but in my server only event is working and listener is not working.

i have added my event service provider, event and listener below .

this code is working fine in my local but in server only log from event is is coming up. not even the log from the constructor of listener coming up. is there anything wrong in my code ? do i have to change anything in server ?

i've cleared the cache, restarted the queue and it is working in server

**EventServiceProvider**

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        NewLeadAdded::class => [
            NewLeadToOutboundAPI::class,
        ],
        // Registered::class => [
        //     SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        // ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
    }
}
```

**Event**

```
class NewLeadAdded
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($lead)
    {
        $this->lead = $lead;
        \logger('this log is from event'); //this is working
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
class NewLeadToOutboundAPI
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        \logger('this log is from listener _construct'); //not working
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  NewLeadAdded  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(NewLeadAdded $event)
    {
        \logger('in listener'); // not working
        $lead = $event->lead;


        $activePlan...
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing "shouldBroadast" on your event class? Also make sure that composer adds the listener to the autoload with "composer dump-autoload -o"

Comment: try `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko tried that. no change.

Comment: Looks like an environment issue, have you checked your configurations for broadcasting in your server, and make sure that the driver you using, is up and running? e.g. if you are using redis, is your redis up and running?

Comment: I had a similar issue that baffled me for quite some time.  For me what @ChanYungKeat said did the trick.  In my `.env` file I simply updated `BROADCAST_DRIVER=log` to `BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis` and restarted my docker compose environment.

Answer (score 3):

Have you imported your Event and Listener in the EventServiceProvider? You must import those Classes in order to make it work.